# Xen is unable to use URL's to install CentOS

Tags: centos, virtualization, xen, web

I can't seem to use URL's when using the netinstall for CentOS, I'm installing CentOS on a Xen VPS.

I keep getting this error in the terminal window, when I use the URL:

```
          ┌────────────────┤ Error ├────────────────┐
          │                                         │
          │ Unable to retrieve                      │
          │ http://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/linux/cen │
          │ tos/6.3/os/x86_64/images/install.img.  │
          │                                         │
          │                 ┌────┐                  │
          │                 │ OK │                  │
          │                 └────┘                  │
          │                                         │
          │                                         │
          └─────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

The URL is perfectly valid, I have no idea why it's not working, I think it may be something to do with my

This is the command that I use to initiate the install on my Dom0:

```
virt-install --name vmTestio8 --ram 513 --vcpus 1 -f /home/xen/domains/vmTestio8.img --network bridge=xenbr0 --location http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.3/os/x86_64/
```

My network settings seem to verify okay with CentOS so I don't see why it's only doing it when it comes to this point, because before when I entered bad data it would throw an error, so I don't know why it's doing this now?

Any ideas?

Server Specs:
Running CentOS 5.9 with XEN

Trying to install CentOS 6.3 on the VPS that I'm creating.

Comment: What are your proxy settings? Also, several of your sentences are missing some

Comment: I don't think I have proxy settings, how do I check? The server is with OVH/Kimsufi

Comment: That xenbr0 is actually connected to a device that has direct access to the internet?